# org-mode special blocks latex attribute

Tags: org-mode, latex

I am using special blocks to create myself a theorem environment so that I can style it in both HTML and Latex output. For this I do;

```
#+BEGIN_theorem
 ---Theorem goes here----
#+END_theorem
```

and this expands into Latex as

```
\begin{theorem}
 ---Theorem goes here----
\end{theorem}
```

But I want to pass an optional argument to this special block so that when I do;

```
#+BEGIN_theorem
#+ATTR_LATEX :theorem_name "Mean Value Thorem"
 ---Theorem goes here----
#+END_theorem
```

so that it will expand into;

```
\begin{theorem}[Mean Value Theorem]
 ---Theorem goes here----
\end{theorem}
```

So, basically I want to pass argument to Latex expansion through special blocks. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following example

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options [Mean Value Theorem]
#+begin_theorem
This is a theorem
#+end_theorem
```

produces

```
\begin{theorem}[Mean Value Theorem]
This is a theorem
\end{theorem}
```

The `:options` keyword is in the last section of the [manual page](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html) for LaTeX block attributes.